# How does this thing appear at that moment?

Tags: plot-explanation, suzume

In the movie Suzume, there is a scene where the aunt screams at Suzume, accusing her of taking away her youth.

At the time she's screaming, she seems to be out of control, like something has possessed her.

We also see Daijin hissing at the aunt.

The next thing we know is Sadaijin has appeared.

Daijin gained its freedom to move only because Suzume took it out when it was the keystone.

My question is:
Without anyone removing the keystone, how does Sadaijin show up behind the aunt in that scene? Who set it free?

Comment: The Sadaijin seems to have been possessing the aunt, but how and when was it free to roam about and who set it free is not answered in the movie.

Comment: @John - I'm wondering why such a critical information was left out in the film.